# Eclipse - Java code templates's cursor jumps to first variable instead of ${cursor} position

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In my Eclipse Mars.2, I have this `try/catch` template now: ("Java - Editor - Templates")

```
try {
    ${cursor}
} catch (${Exception} ${exception_variable_name}) {

}
```

Upon insertion, the cursor jumps to `${Exception}` instead of where `${cursor}` is. How can I make the cursor to be at where it should be?

I also want to add another "tab-jumping-point" in the body of `catch` block. How it can be done?